# Flutter Application crashes on ios when changing tab of DefaultTabBarController

Tags: ios, flutter, dart

MY application consist of both bottom and upper tabs, I am calling a network request on each tab but sometimes it crash application on iOS and don't know the reason for this.
Below are logs i got on crashlytics.

```js
Fatal Exception: NSInternalInconsistencyException
0  CoreFoundation                 0x199a9b180 __exceptionPreprocess
1  libobjc.A.dylib                0x198c739f8 objc_exception_throw
2  CoreFoundation                 0x1999b488c +[_CFXNotificationTokenRegistration keyCallbacks]
3  Foundation                     0x19a478b38 -[NSAssertionHandler handleFailureInMethod:object:file:lineNumber:description:]
4  Flutter                        0x1014953ec (Missing)
5  Runner                         0x101062c30 +[GeneratedPluginRegistrant registerWithRegistry:] + 88 (GeneratedPluginRegistrant.m:88)
6  flutter_downloader             0x101f77404 (Missing)
7  flutter_downloader             0x101f7a850 (Missing)
8  flutter_downloader             0x101f7d218 (Missing)
9  Flutter                        0x101517768 (Missing)
10 Flutter                        0x1014b2240 (Missing)
11 Flutter                        0x101508398 (Missing)
12 Flutter                        0x1014c1fd0 (Missing)
13 Flutter                        0x1014c3c48 (Missing)
14 CoreFoundation                 0x199a2d554 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_TIMER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__
15 CoreFoundation                 0x199a2d284 __CFRunLoopDoTimer
16 CoreFoundation                 0x199a2cab8 __CFRunLoopDoTimers
17 CoreFoundation                 0x199a27a08 __CFRunLoopRun
18 CoreFoundation                 0x199a26fb4 CFRunLoopRunSpecific
19 GraphicsServices               0x19bc2879c GSEventRunModal
20 UIKitCore                      0x1c6288c38 UIApplicationMain
21 Runner                         0x1010633bc main + 8 (AppDelegate.swift:8)
22 libdyld.dylib                  0x1994ea8e0 start
```

```js
Crashed: com.twitter.crashlytics.ios.exception
0  Runner                         0x10107cc20 CLSProcessRecordAllThreads + 4308732960
1  Runner                         0x10107d008 CLSProcessRecordAllThreads + 4308733960
2  Runner                         0x10106c874 CLSHandler + 4308666484
3  Runner                         0x10107b218 __CLSExceptionRecord_block_invoke + 4308726296
4  libdispatch.dylib              0x1994d97d4 _dispatch_client_callout + 16
5  libdispatch.dylib              0x199487c1c _dispatch_lane_barrier_sync_invoke_and_complete + 56
6  Runner                         0x10107ac84 CLSExceptionRecord + 4308724868
7  Runner                         0x10107aab0 CLSExceptionRecordNSException + 4308724400
8  Runner                         0x10107a6a4 CLSTerminateHandler() + 4308723364
9  libc++abi.dylib                0x198c68838 std::__terminate(void (*)()) + 16
10 libc++abi.dylib                0x198c68434 __cxa_rethrow + 144
11 libobjc.A.dylib                0x198c73bc8 objc_exception_rethrow + 44
12 CoreFoundation                 0x199a27020 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 544
13 GraphicsServices               0x19bc2879c GSEventRunModal + 104
14 UIKitCore                      0x1c6288c38 UIApplicationMain + 212
15 Runner                         0x1010633bc main + 8 (AppDelegate.swift:8)
16 libdyld.dylib                  0x1994ea8e0 start + 4
```

I am stuck at this and couldn't find any reason or solution. 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

What version of crashlytics are you running? If you are running iOS 13 you should upgrade to 3.14.0. as it will give you better detailed information about the crash.

Comment: i am getting this crash on both iOS 12 & 13